pgfpages layout "two screens with optional second" with "second top" do not show shading picture correctly
In the following code, a shading colour is created firstly, and then used in pgfpicture to show it in the top of the second logical page. When using option "second right" for the layout "two screens with optional second", everything is OK. However, changing "second right" to "second top" the shading colour also disappear. How to make the option "second top" show the shading picture correctly?
\documentclass[a5paper, landscape]{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfpages}

# WITH OPTION "second right", everything is OK.
\pgfpagesuselayout{two screens with optional second}[second top]

\pgfdeclareverticalshading{headfade}{\paperwidth}%
{%
  rgb(0cm)=(0.9, 0.9, 0.9);
  rgb(3cm)=(0.8, 0.8, 0.9)%
}

\begin{document}

{\Huge Text for main page.}
\clearpage

\pgfpagescurrentpagewillbelogicalpage{2}
{\Huge Text that goes to second page.}

\pgfrememberpicturepositiononpagetrue
\begin{pgfpicture}
  \pgfusepath{use as bounding box}
  \pgftransformshift{\pgfpointanchor{current page}{north west}}
  \pgftext[top, left]{\pgfuseshading{headfade}}
\end{pgfpicture}

\end{document}

The result pdf with option:"second right"

The result pdf with option:"second top"

